# Viewport vs. camera view performance really awful

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I’m trying to compose an amimation. Scene is comprised of several buildings, trees, woods, lo-poly cars etc. Moving around the viewport works super smooth, can’t say how many fps, but it’s smooth enough.

When I switch to camera view though, I get like 0.6 fps, same view mode. Moving the camera in camera view or playing back the animation is really slow. What’s the difference between viewport/camera view that causes such a huge difference and is there a way to fix it?

I already followed all steps in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lt04spiTkdM
no change, at least not that I'd realize. Somplify is on, all options set to zero, all viewport shading options are off, grass/plant geometry invisible in VP. If I set playback to drop frames, I get to see 3 frames of 100. If I turn on trees/vegetation, I jump from 2 million faces to 8, yet there's no apparent speed decrease.

Camera is parented to an empty, which is moving along a path, tracking via another empty. But that can't be the reason, since simply moving the camera - in camera view - is super sluggish!

I also just tried to view the animation in viewport, from anywhere else: also terribly slow, whereas navigating is fast. How is it that hard for my comp to play back that primitive animation?

Comment: Are you in material preview mode? If so having depth of field on the camera can quickly deteriorate the fps.

Comment: Try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lt04spiTkdM

Comment: Is there a difference between your render distance of your viewport and camera? Does changing this affect playback speed?

Comment: You might also want to try creating a new camera: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79873/viewport-performance-changes-when-in-camera?rq=1

Comment: I had this problem with grass and camera clipping, where the camera still decides what part of the grass it can see, even if it's not visible. If you have this enabled, then that might be your problem